# Writing an SQL query to SELECT item from the following table

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, ms-access

I am having a really hard time writing a SELECT query to get a hold of the data in the following table...

Here is a picture of the table...

http://i44.tinypic.com/29dxx81.png

I am trying to display the names of the parts (pname) for all item parts that have a quantity larger than 10... However, the quantity seems to appear only when the submenu is expanded, and I am having trouble SELECT'ing it...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT pname from [TableName] WHERE quantity >= 10
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT pname from Parts 
INNER JOIN Shipments
ON Parts.ForeignKey = Shipments.ForeignKey
WHERE quantity >= 10
```

Comment: Yes that DOESNT work. ... I know how to write basic SQL... this requires more then a simple SELECT x FROM y WHERE z < 10...

Comment: what program is the image from? I have not seen a record that expands before.. is that linked data to another table?

Comment: The image is from ACCESS. Yes there is a table called Shipments that has a quantity column (without having to expand) .... how would I write the query asking to evaluate data from an table B to SELECT info from table A?

Comment: wouldn't something like this work... SELECT pname FROM Parts WHERE quantity IN( SELECT quantity FROM shipments > 10);  ??? I tried it and it doesn't work, and I feel like i'm close...  I don't think I should be dealing with foreign keys or inner joins, I appreciate the info though... :)

Comment: How does that Part relate to the Shipment. They have to be tied together. Else it wont just return random data. They need to be linked. Your asking for a part that is related to a shipment where quantity is >= 10. Does Shipments table have pnum in it?